# How to delete one word forward in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

Delete one word backward:

```
Ctrl + w
```

Delete one word forward:

```
?
```

Can anyone answer the above or do I need to add a command to stty as I can see by running the following command:

```
stty -a
```

that the action associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> is defined there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The key sequence is `M-d` in `bash`, i.e. <kbd>Alt+D</kbd> or <kbd>Esc+D</kbd>.

This invokes the `kill-word` Readline function:

> `kill-word` (`M-d`)
>
> Kill from point to the end of the current word, or if between
>             words, to the end of the next word.  Word boundaries are the
>             same as those used by `forward-word`.

The above is taken from the `bash` manual.

Comment: It's M-d like in emacs when in emacs mode and dw or dW like in vi when in vi mode.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks very much. I can confirm alt+d will delete the next word in front of the cursor in bash.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Thank you, to be honest i'm very new to Linux/Vim I am having trouble understanding this notation M-d, I would interpret that as Shift+m+d  but obviously this is incorrect. I can't see how M-d means the same as alt+d?

Comment: The `M` means "Meta".  In general, `X-y` means "press the `X` key with `y`" as in "`C-c` is Control with `c`".  Meta is generally the Escape or Alt keys.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks very much for both your answers, very well written in a concise and informative manner, extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: btw this is defined in `readline` not `bash`